# Swift: how to make my custom struct Node<T> conform to Hashable?

Tags: swift, generics, hashable

Node is a generic type.

```
struct Node<T: Hashable>: Hashable {
    var label: T

    init(_ label: T) {
        self.label = label
    }

    var hashValue : Int {
        get {
            return label.hashValue
        }
    }
}

extension Node : Equatable {}

// MARK: Equatable

func ==<T>(lhs: Node<T>, rhs: Node<T>) -> Bool {
    return lhs.label == rhs.label
}
```

But it doesn't work when I try the following:

```
let nodes = Set<Node<String>>()
```

The compiler complains that `Node<String>` doesn't conform to Hashable. How to make `Node<String>` conform to Hashable?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to implement the `==` method as part of the `Equatable` protocol for your struct as well:

```
func ==<T, K>(lhs:Node<T>, rhs:Node<K>) -> Bool {
    return lhs.hashValue == rhs.hashValue
}
```

The reason for that is [`Hashable`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Reference/Swift_Hashable_Protocol/) inherits from [`Equatable`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Reference/Swift_Equatable_Protocol/index.html#//apple_ref/swift/intf/s:PSs9Equatable).

The following is a **complete working playground** example:

```
struct Node<T: Hashable> : Hashable {
    var label: T

    init(_ label: T) {
        self.label = label
    }

    var hashValue : Int {
        get {
            return label.hashValue
        }
    }
}

func ==<T>(lhs:Node<T>, rhs:Node<T>) -> Bool {
    return lhs.hashValue == rhs.hashValue
}

var nodes = Set<Node<String>>()
nodes.insert(Node("hi"))
nodes.insert(Node("ho"))
nodes.insert(Node("hi"))
```

Comment: Updated question. I did implement ==.

Comment: @HuangChao You should not change your question based on the answers. And does it solve the problem? For me it does. No need for the `extension` btw.

Comment: @HuangChao Then you are doing it wrong, the `==` has to be defined at the top level, not inside a class or inside anything else, just below the import statements basically.

Comment: It turns out that the problem has nothing to do with Hashable stuff. It's Xcode issue. I did clean only but not build so that XCode doesn't even notice Node is now Hashable.

Comment: Yes. Thanks for the help.